# Moxy + inheritance + package name as xml-root-element

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to marshall a class that is extending abstract class using eclipseLink moxy:

```
public abstract class AbstractExample {
  private String fieldA;
  private String fieldB;

  // Getters, setters 
}

public class Example extends AbstractExample {
  private String fieldC;
  private String fieldD;

  // More fields, getters and setters
}
```

I use xml for mapping:

```
<java-type name="com.example.Example">
  <xml-root-element name="com.another.package.Example2" />
  <java-attributes>
    <!-- All fields defined here -->
  </java-attributes>
</java-type>
```

Now everything is fine when unmarshalling. Problem appears when I'm marshalling the object. Instead of

```
<com.another.package.Example2>
```

root element I get only

```
<Example2>
```

as root element. What's interesting - as soon as I push the fields from abstract class down into Example, and remove extends AbstractExample keywords, the root is what it should be

```
<com.another.package.Example2>.
```

Am I doing something wrong? I really need to extend the abstract class or my code would have a lot of redundancy.

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't want xml-root-element to be Example's qualified name. I need it to be totally different package and class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead.

This issue turned out to be the following MOXy bug:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/372534

This issue has now been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.3.3 and 2.4.0 streams.  It will be available in the nightly downloads starting tomorrow (Feb 25, 2012):

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php